# Get the attribute value from inner tag of Div tag using jsoup

Tags: jsoup

*i want extract the content  from webpage using jsoup. the values are in inner  tag How will  extract those values?*

**For example**

```
< div id="tfm_skyscraper" class="top_right_skyscraper"></div>
  <nav class="main group">
   <section class="verticals world group" data-beacon="{&quot;p&quot">
    <ul class="verticals-ul">
        <li class="front-page toplevel" data-beacon="{&quot">
        <a class="toplevel-a" href="http://www.huffingtonpost.com" title="Home"  tabindex="1" sl-processed="1">FRONT PAGE</a>*

        </li>                           
    </ul>
 </section>
</nav>
```

i want extract  the content  *FRONT PAGE* in  **anchor tag *** how will do this?

Answer (score 0):

This will print the text of all the link tags with class `toplevel-a`

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String html =   "<div id=\"tfm_skyscraper\" class=\"top_right_skyscraper\"></div>" +
                            "<nav class=\"main group\">" +
                                "<section class=\"verticals world group\" data-beacon=\"{&quot;p&quot\">" +
                                    "<ul class=\"verticals-ul\">" +
                                        "<li class=\"front-page toplevel\" data-beacon=\"{&quot\">" +
                                            "<a class=\"toplevel-a\" href=\"http://www.huffingtonpost.com\" title=\"Home\" tabindex=\"1\" sl-processed=\"1\">FRONT PAGE</a>*" +
                                        "</li>" +                           
                                    "</ul>" +
                                "</section>" +
                            "</nav>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements els = doc.select("a.toplevel-a");
        for(Element el : els) {
            System.out.println(el.text());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can i extract the value directly from the url using jsoup
 tag values  are like 
FRONT PAGE POLITICS BUSINESS ENTERTAINMENT MEDIA etc
  could u please Clear my dobut?
 i try this way this is correct  i got only one tag values 
Example:

Document doc ;
doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/11/23/israel-new-laws_n_6207042.html#comments").get();
Elements linktag=doc.select("ul.verticals-ul").select("li").select("a.toplevel-a");
  Iterator<Element>itrlinktag=linktag.iterator();
        while(itrlinktag.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(itrlinktag.next().text());
        }

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: My Question is you convert the each tag as string after that extract the values. with out convert tag  to String extract the values is possible ?

Comment: I still don't understand.

Comment: ok leave it ask another question?
How to reterive the no of comments and who put the commands on the videos (i.e)  Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFccvtrP1d8&list=PLV-cxl3VSwWEZPb6yEvQaf68_yY8chu8U
u will take this videos link on that 
All commands: 561
Baby Games Toys & ABC Songs1 week ago
Great Video :) keep it up
Reply  ·  14

Great Video :) keep it up
Reply  ·  14
View all 52 replies

Martin Arceo Jr.8 hours ago
 
Bww
Reply  ·  

Wassana Koykoy4 hours ago
 
จ๊ะจิงจา
Translate
Reply  ·  

Childrenofworld20142 weeks ago
 
the best kid songs
Reply  ·  7

Comment: In youtube the comments are loaded via javascript (ajax). Jsoup cannot handle javascript content. You need a headless browser for that (htmlunit, selenium webdriver). Although you should ask a new question for that
.

Comment: Why Exception Raised while Retrieving the Youtube Elements using iterator in Jsoup? 
I posted the My code in Same title
Could u Please Help me?